# How to find all Confluence pages with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I'm trying to pull *all* Confluence pages in my instance that haven't been modified since 1/1/21.  I was able to get all of the parent pages that haven't been modified since 1/1/21 fairly easily.  However, I'm now trying to get all of the *child* pages.

I know `get-confluencechildpage` has a `-recurse` option ([source](https://atlassianps.org/docs/ConfluencePS/)) but when I use it I get `Invoke-Method : Page children is currently only supported for direct children`.

I've created a script that will iterate through the top level pages and check if there are child pages.  What I can't figure out is how to setup the do until and not duplicate the child page output, see picture below.

Here's what I have so far.  Once I can get the `get-confluencechildpage` figured out I can then add an if and base it on date modified.  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Please and thank you.

```
$Pages = get-confluencespace -spacekey 'SPACEKEY' | get-confluencepage
$NotMod = $pages | ? { $_.version.when -lt (get-date 1/1/21) }
$full = @()
foreach ($1 in $notmod) {
    $full += get-confluencepage $1.id
    if ($1 | Get-ConfluenceChildPage) {
        $Descendents = $1 | Get-ConfluenceChildPage
        foreach ($child in $Descendents) {
            $full += $child
            do {
                $Next = 1
                $Next = $child | Get-ConfluenceChildPage
                if ($next) {
                    $full += $next
                }
            } until (
                $null -eq $Next
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Output of script]

Comment: 2 possible options: just add the duplicates and select distinct at the end: `Get-Unique $full` or check if the variable already contains the value before adding it `if($full -notcontains $next){$full+=$next}`

Comment: Can't do the ```get-unique $full``` idea because the script gets stuck in a perpetual loop.

The ```if ($full -notconatins $next)``` idea I'm exploring.  I'm getting parent page duplicates now, so I'm figuring that part out now.  That may be something that happens just do to the architecture of Confluence.  I can use the ```get-unique``` item at the end to dedup the list.

Comment: None of the above worked, I either got stuck in an infinite loop or the child pages didn't append.

Comment: Given that the child pages can have their own child pages as well, you probably want to do something like “$root = get space home page; push $root onto a stack; $allpages = empty list; while(stack not empty) { $parent = pop stack; add parent to $allpages; $children = get child pages; push children onto stack }”.  Then you can filter $allpages for your modified date. I can take a look later this evening if no-one else replies in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested Atlassian's `ConfluencePS` module (v2.5.1) on a self-hosted Confluence instance (v7.3.5), and the `Get-ConfluencePage` cmdlet **appears** to return a flattened list of the entire document tree for a given space.

Based on that, your code would simply be:

```
# get all pages from a Confluence "Space"
$all_pages = Get-ConfluencePage -SpaceKey "myspacekey";

# filter all the pages to just get those last edited before a specified date
$timestamp = (get-date -Year 2021 -Month 1 -Day 1).Date;
$filtered  = $pages | where-object { $_.Version.When -lt $timestamp };

$filtered | format-table "Id"

   ID
   --
17714
67261
..etc
```

**Update**

If, for whatever reason, you don't get all the pages in the Space returned from `Get-ConfluencePage`, you could do a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) of the root pages in the tree using `Get-ConfluenceChildPage`:

```
# get root pages in the space
$rootPages = ...

# push root pages onto a stack
$stack = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach( $rootPage in $rootPages )
{
    $null = $stack.Add($rootPage);
}

# initialise the result set
$all_pages = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList;

# while stack not empty
while( $stack.Count -gt 0 )
{

    # pop the top page off the stack
    $parent = $stack[$stack.Count - 1];
    $stack.RemoveAt($stack.Count - 1);

    # add the top page to the result set
    $null = $all_pages.Add($parent);

    # get child pages
    write-host "getting child pages for '$($parent.Title)' ($($parent.ID))";
    $children = Get-ConfluenceChildPage -PageId $parent.ID;
    write-host ($children | format-table | out-string);

    # push child pages onto the stack
    foreach( $child in $children )
    {
        $null = $stack.Add($child);
    }

}
```

Comment: When I use the commandlet I get a flat list of all parent pages, it does not contain any sub pages.

Comment: Weird. I definitely get a flattened list of the entire tree of documents in a space. What versions of the ConfluencePS module and your Confluence instance are you using?

Comment: @topcity36 - I’ve also added an update that walks the page tree to get all pages - see if that works…

Comment: Boom!  That worked like a champ, thanks.  I'll keep your method in mind for other stuff moving forward as well.